# Get intelliSense info inside VS extension

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, intellisense, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm trying to write an extension to IntelliSense in Visual Studio 2015.

Right now you can write code something like

```
constexpr auto res = offset(ClassName, fieldName);
```

And when you put your mouse over the `res` variable, VS IntelliSense will show you the result of the method, e.g. offset of the field `fieldName` inside `ClassName` class.

Is there a way to:

- get information about the offset from the IntelliSense or
- evaluate custom code on the selected text from VS extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to:
>   get information about the offset from the IntelliSense or
>   evaluate custom code on the selected text from VS extension?

Unfortunately, the C++ Intellisense feature doesn't allow for something like this. If you were working with the Roslyn based C# or VB.NET compilers, the story is a bit different, as you can access the same pipeline the C# or VB.Net Intellisense features use. But C++ Intellisense is an entirely different beast

Comment: thank you, @Leo-MSFT, for the answer! I haven't voted for your answer at MSDN forum yet only because I was checking the other one.
Just of curiosity, do you have any relations with VS developers? I asking only to find an easy way for proposing features for VS)

Comment: If you want to propose features for VS, you can submit a user voice here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.